# Where was the Deepground in Original Final Fantasy VII?

Tags: final-fantasy

I'm wondering about the whereabouts of Deepground in the Final Fantasy VII. i know they are already existing but their whereabouts were not said in Crisis Core or in Dirge of Cerberus

Comment: While I havne't played the games after the original, I've looked around and I think your question might be a bit ambiguous due to you once using an article and once skipping it. Are we talking about the group *Deepground* or the location *Deepground* (City)?

Comment: @Mario The group

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick perusal of the Final Fantasy wiki turned this up...

> The Deepground facility underneath Midgar was built the same time the
>   Shinra Headquarters, in 1976 as a medical lab for wounded SOLDIER
>   members, and to house Mako Reactor 0 to power the facility and the
>   Shinra Building above it.

and this...

> The combined force of Meteor and Holy crushing down on Midgar sealed
>   the soldiers [Deepground] beneath the Shinra Tower, trapping them until their
>   escape three years later.

So, the Deepground forces and facilities were underneath Midgar, and that's where they were during the events of FFVII. While there is nothing that says what the individuals of Deepground were doing while Sephiroth was having his rampage, and Cloud & Co were saving the world, it is clear that they were all in the Deepground facility, beneath the center of Midgar, when Meteor/Holy happened.

Comment: I see, so they're were all stuck there the whole time. now i am wondering the time duration Original Final Fantasy 7 took